# NP532 doesn't detect NTAG213 tag

Tags: adafruit, nfc

I'm using a [PN532 module](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/4001169120990.html) to read/write [NTAG213 tags](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/32960281764.html). They both should be working at 13.56 MHZ, and [Adafruit should support these tags in their library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-PN532/blob/master/examples/ntag2xx_read/ntag2xx_read.ino).

The Arduino Uno board and the module are connected as follows

```
PN532 Module  |  Arduino Uno
--------------+-------------
VCC           |  5V
GND           |  GND
SCK           |  D2
MI            |  D5
MO/SDA/TX     |  D3
NSS           |  D4
```

SPI is enabled on the PN532 module:

```
SET 0 -> L
SET 1 -> H
```

[Using the `ntag2xx_read` example provided by the library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-PN532/blob/master/examples/ntag2xx_read/ntag2xx_read.ino), I can pick up MIFARE tags, with an error thrown in the Serial Monitor.

```
This doesn't seem to be an NTAG203 tag (UUID length != 7 bytes)!
```

So far, so good. But when I try to place one of my NTAG213 tags, ***nothing happens***. I thought maybe I'd need to change [the page read to match NTAG213 specs (instead of default NTAG203)](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-PN532/blob/master/examples/ntag2xx_read/ntag2xx_read.ino#L114) but unsurprisingly id didn't change anything.

I'm not sure where to go from there. I don't know whether there's some hardware incompatibility or if I'm missing something in the setup or the code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The NTAG213 tags can be read with a smartphone.

---

The code I'm using is exactly the same as the one linked from the library above (besides page read), I'm pasting it here for future reference

```
/**************************************************************************/
/*! 
    @file     readntag203.pde
    @author   KTOWN (Adafruit Industries)
    @license  BSD (see license.txt)

    This example will wait for any NTAG203 or NTAG213 card or tag,
    and will attempt to read from it.

    This is an example sketch for the Adafruit PN532 NFC/RFID breakout boards
    This library works with the Adafruit NFC breakout 
      ----> https://www.adafruit.com/products/364
 
    Check out the links above for our tutorials and wiring diagrams 
    These chips use SPI or I2C to communicate.

    Adafruit invests time and resources providing this open source code, 
    please support Adafruit and open-source hardware by purchasing 
    products from Adafruit!
*/
/**************************************************************************/
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Adafruit_PN532.h>

// If using the breakout with SPI, define the pins for SPI communication.
#define PN532_SCK  (2)
#define PN532_MOSI (3)
#define PN532_SS   (4)
#define PN532_MISO (5)

// If using the breakout or shield with I2C, define just the pins connected
// to the IRQ and reset lines.  Use the values below (2, 3) for the shield!
#define PN532_IRQ   (2)
#define PN532_RESET (3)  // Not connected by default on the NFC Shield

// Uncomment just _one_ line below depending on how your breakout or shield
// is connected to the Arduino:

// Use this line for a breakout with a software SPI connection (recommended):
Adafruit_PN532 nfc(PN532_SCK, PN532_MISO, PN532_MOSI, PN532_SS);

// Use this line for a breakout with a hardware SPI connection.  Note that
// the PN532 SCK, MOSI, and MISO pins need to be connected to the Arduino's
// hardware SPI SCK, MOSI, and MISO pins.  On an Arduino Uno these are
// SCK = 13, MOSI = 11, MISO = 12.  The SS line can be any digital IO pin.
//Adafruit_PN532 nfc(PN532_SS);

// Or use this line for a breakout or shield with an I2C connection:
//Adafruit_PN532 nfc(PN532_IRQ, PN532_RESET);


void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial) delay(10); // for Leonardo/Micro/Zero

  Serial.println("Hello!");

  nfc.begin();

  uint32_t versiondata = nfc.getFirmwareVersion();
  if (! versiondata) {
    Serial.print("Didn't find PN53x board");
    while (1); // halt
  }
  // Got ok data, print it out!
  Serial.print("Found chip PN5"); Serial.println((versiondata>>24) & 0xFF, HEX); 
  Serial.print("Firmware ver. "); Serial.print((versiondata>>16) & 0xFF, DEC); 
  Serial.print('.'); Serial.println((versiondata>>8) & 0xFF, DEC);
  
  // configure board to read RFID tags
  nfc.SAMConfig();
  
  Serial.println("Waiting for an ISO14443A Card ...");
}

void loop(void) {
  uint8_t success;
  uint8_t uid[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };  // Buffer to store the returned UID
  uint8_t uidLength;                        // Length of the UID (4 or 7 bytes depending on ISO14443A card type)
    
  // Wait for an NTAG203 card.  When one is found 'uid' will be populated with
  // the UID, and uidLength will indicate the size of the UUID (normally 7)
  success = nfc.readPassiveTargetID(PN532_MIFARE_ISO14443A, uid, &uidLength);
  
  if (success) {
    // Display some basic information about the card
    Serial.println("Found an ISO14443A card");
    Serial.print("  UID Length: ");Serial.print(uidLength, DEC);Serial.println(" bytes");
    Serial.print("  UID Value: ");
    nfc.PrintHex(uid, uidLength);
    Serial.println("");
    
    if (uidLength == 7)
    {
      uint8_t data[32];
      
      // We probably have an NTAG2xx card (though it could be Ultralight as well)
      Serial.println("Seems to be an NTAG2xx tag (7 byte UID)");      
      
      // NTAG2x3 cards have 39*4 bytes of user pages (156 user bytes),
      // starting at page 4 ... larger cards just add pages to the end of
      // this range:
      
      // See: http://www.nxp.com/documents/short_data_sheet/NTAG203_SDS.pdf

      // TAG Type       PAGES   USER START    USER STOP
      // --------       -----   ----------    ---------
      // NTAG 203       42      4             39
      // NTAG 213       45      4             39
      // NTAG 215       135     4             129
      // NTAG 216       231     4             225      

      for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 45; i++) 
      {
        success = nfc.ntag2xx_ReadPage(i, data);
        
        // Display the current page number
        Serial.print("PAGE ");
        if (i < 10)
        {
          Serial.print("0");
          Serial.print(i);
        }
        else
        {
          Serial.print(i);
        }
        Serial.print(": ");

        // Display the results, depending on 'success'
        if (success) 
        {
          // Dump the page data
          nfc.PrintHexChar(data, 4);
        }
        else
        {
          Serial.println("Unable to read the requested page!");
        }
      }      
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.println("This doesn't seem to be an NTAG203 tag (UUID length != 7 bytes)!");
    }
    
    // Wait a bit before trying again
    Serial.println("\n\nSend a character to scan another tag!");
    Serial.flush();
    while (!Serial.available());
    while (Serial.available()) {
    Serial.read();
    }
    Serial.flush();    
  }
}
```

And nothing happens in the monitor after the setup

```
22:28:56.855 -> Hello!
22:28:56.888 -> Found chip PN532
22:28:56.888 -> Firmware ver. 1.6
22:28:56.922 -> Waiting for an ISO14443A Card ...
```

If I uncomment `#define PN532DEBUG` in `Adafruit_PN532.cpp`, I get some extra logs but still none when I pass my NTAG213 tag. Adding a timeout doesn't help the tag to be detected either.

```
// Passing the NTAG213 here
15:51:00.519 -> Sending : 0x0, 0x0, 0xFF, 0x4, 0xFC, 0xD4, 0x4A, 0x1, 0x0, 0xE1, 0x0, 
15:51:01.582 -> TIMEOUT!
15:51:01.582 -> No card(s) read
15:51:01.582 -> Sending : 0x0, 0x0, 0xFF, 0x4, 0xFC, 0xD4, 0x4A, 0x1, 0x0, 0xE1, 0x0, 
15:51:02.614 -> TIMEOUT!
15:51:02.614 -> No card(s) read
15:51:02.614 -> Sending : 0x0, 0x0, 0xFF, 0x4, 0xFC, 0xD4, 0x4A, 0x1, 0x0, 0xE1, 0x0, 

// Passing another tag here
15:51:03.212 -> Reading:  0x0 0x0 0xFF 0xC 0xF4 0xD5 0x4B 0x1 0x1 0x0 0x4 0x8 0x4 0x47 0xF5 0xC 0xD8 0xAE 0x0 0xAA
15:51:03.212 -> Found an ISO14443A card
15:51:03.212 ->   UID Length: 4 bytes
15:51:03.249 ->   UID Value: 0x47 0xF5 0x0C 0xD8
15:51:03.249 -> 
15:51:03.249 -> This doesn't seem to be an NTAG203 tag (UUID length != 7 bytes)!
15:51:03.249 -> 
15:51:03.249 -> 
15:51:03.249 -> Send a character to scan another tag!
```

Comment: I have no special knowledge the related NFC topics, but I have been looking over everything you've referenced and I noticed `nfc.SAMConfig()` returns a bool value to indicate success on true (I think).  For lack of anything more intelligent to suggest for now, I thought maybe you might see that this is call is indicating success.

Comment: A fair mount of useful debugging information may come from uncommenting `PN532DEBUG` and `MIFAREDEBUG` (https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-PN532/blob/1.2.1/Adafruit_PN532.cpp#L67) in Adafruit_PN532.cpp.  Might help to include that information with the question.

Comment: Thanks for commenting @timemage. `nfc.SAMConfig()` returns 1 so this seems ok I think. I've tried adding the debug macros in the .ino file but it didn't print any additional info. I haven't tried to recompile the library yet, as I have never done it before.

Comment: It is usually enough to edit the source in place and just compile again.  In the past, I believe the IDE has incorrectly cached object files.  You can restart the IDE to get it to use a new temporarily build directory to prevent that from happening.  You may need to change the macro for the Serial port the library is using to print diagnostics.

Comment: @timemage I did t didn't get any more luck :/ It still doesn't print anything when i try to pass the tag on the reader. I do see extra logs when I pass another tag but it's still not detecting the NTAG213

Comment: What happens if you use the version of the `readPassiveTargetID()` that accepts a timeout?  Does it in fact timeout or does it lock up inside the function?

Comment: @timemage It loops until it detects something. With a NTAG213 it keeps going as if nothing happened, and then stops when detecting another tag. I've updated the question with the logs from `PN532DEBUG` and `readPassiveTargetID()` with a timeout

Comment: I'll keep looking at it.  I get the sense though that someone who knows this library and part will be able to say something useful based on the information you have in the question now.

Comment: Well, I'm curious about this stuff.  So, you should know I've ordered some things to test with here.  Some NTAG213 and a reader using the PN532, though not your exact board.  Perhaps within the week I'll be able to test locally.

Comment: Have you checked your tag with other readers? Many smartphones should be able to read (and write to) such tags, if that helps.

Comment: @timemage I truly appreciate your involvment in this :) I've also contacted the sellers just in case

Comment: @jcaron You're right, I absolutely meant to test the tags with a phone but I forgot. Mine doesn't support NFC but I live with a person who owns such a phone. I'll try that and let you know.

Comment: I have tags, but my board for testing won't come until Tuesday at the earliest.  I'm not sure how much longer I'm going to be on arduino.stackexchange.com.  I can be found on freenode if you want to talk there.

Comment: Received my board a day early it seems.  Wired it as described.  Using the code given unaltered on an UNO.  When I try an NTAG213, it recognizes it, prints the 7 byte UID, and proceeds to dump 4-byte pages numbered 0 to 44 inclusive.

Comment: @timemage Looking back on the PN532 link I initially provided, I think it might be a reader issue. It states that it supports ISO14443 but I couldn't find NTAG213 mentioned anywhere. I expected it to work because PN532 usually do but apparently this one doesn't. I contacted the vendor but they haven't been of much help knowing what their product supports or not. I've also tried reading the tags with a smartphone, and didn't have any problem doing so.

Comment: What you're saying seems to hinge on the idea that, since we're running the same code, that the PN532 can be configured to work (or not) with NTAG213 and that this configuration must exist in some non-volatile way, as part of the circuit construction or built-in eeprom etc.  I can't seem to substantiate that idea.

Comment: @timemage I'm not 100% sure I understood your last comment. I'll try my best to reformulate what I understood. I thought - seemingly wrongly - that _any_ PN532 module would be able to work with NTAG213 because a quick google search indicates that these two can be compatible. However PN532 does not seem to be follow a specific norm or specification. Therefore simply being a PN532 module is not enough to ensure compatibility with NTAG213.

Comment: I'm not sure what more I can do while staying inside the stack-exchange format.  If you want, you can locate me on freenode.  If we come to a conclusion, you can write up your experience an answer to your own question.